# How to get text based off 'Minimal Xpath'?

Tags: xml, xpath, firebug, greasemonkey

I'm looking at a page in firebug, and have identified the different sections of content I need to get the text from. Firebug offers the ability to copy Xpath or Minimal Xpath.

```
Xpath: /html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/form/div[2]/div/span[2]/input
Minimal Xpath: //*[@id="SeatCount"]
```

I am trying to write a script for greasemonkey that grabs the text based off this content. 
I was able to get the content from one of the fields using this bit:

```
 var returnedValue = document.getElementById("SeatCount").textContent;
```

I'm wondering if I can achieve something similarly using Xpath or better yet the 'Minimal Xpath' (I don't know if the 'minimal xpath' has a more specific name that that format goes by?)

Is it possible to use the xpath option(s) to get the associated textcontent? If so, how?

Comment: For elements that have id's, `getElementById` is always easier and faster than XPath. Use it. ... For all other cases, `document.querySelectorAll()` will almost always be easier and more robust than XPath.

Answer (score 3):

The path that is labeled "XPath" represents the the absolute location path of the element you want to select as a sequence of steps from the root node. It's based on positional predicates, which means that if you add or remove anything in the structure of the file, it's location path may change.

The path called "Minimal XPath" is an expression that uses the *descendant-or-self". It also starts from the root node but matches *any* element in the entire file that has an `id` attribute containing the value `SeatCount`. This is usually better because you don't depend on file structure, and the `id` can guarantee that you are retrieving an unique result.

You can select using [XPath](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath) in JavaScript using the `evaluate` function. For example:

```
var result = document.evaluate('//*[@id="SeatCount"]', document, null, XPathResult.ANY_UNORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null );
```

**CORRECTIONS**: I replaced *node* for *result* in the answer above and changed the node type constant. As @MartinHonnen correctly observed, `evaluate()` doesn't return a node but an object from where you can extract nodes. In you case, since you have a single result, you can use `singleNodeValue` to obtain that node. If your node has text content, you can retrieve that content using:

```
var contents = result.singleNodeValue.textContent;
```

See [MDN: XPath JavaScript documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript) and [MDN: Using XPath](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_XPath)

Comment: The `evaluate` method is the right suggestion to apply an XPath expression but your snippet suggests it returns a node, it never does, instead it returns an object with properties and methods like the `singleNodeValue` property you could use as long as you use a result type with evaluate that returns a single node.

Comment: Thanks @MartinHonnen. I updated the answer with that correction.

Comment: `singleNodeValue` is not going to work with the result type you have used, you will need to change it to `var result = document.evaluate('//*[@id="SeatCount"]', document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null );` or to `ANY_UNORDERED_NODE_TYPE`.

Comment: Fixed. Thanks again @MartinHonnen (I should have tested it before posting to avoid these errors)